# mail() send 2 copies

Tags: php, email, gmail

I try to write the PHP script, which can send HTML mails to my e-mail.
I've done it, but when i use the url to send it, i receive normal mail, and about 1 hour after i receive "bad" mail

This is query:
    URL?sendTo=mail&theme=Theme&info=SomeData&username=Test&token=secret_key

PHP Code( i don't know how to paste code here):

```php
header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8");

$sendTo         = $_GET['sendTo'];
$theme          = $_GET['theme'];
$info           = $_GET['info'];
$username       = $_GET['username'];
$key            = $_GET['key'];

$theme          = iconv("windows-1251", "utf-8", $_GET['theme']);
$info           = iconv("windows-1251", "utf-8", $_GET['info']);
$username       = mb_convert_encoding($username, "utf-8", "windows-1251");

$token          = $_GET['token'];
$secret_token   = 'fseffse6755467adwfGFYTDdbmjrfg';

if($secret_token != $token)
    die('Sorry, invalid secret key :(');


if(empty($sendTo) || empty($theme) || empty($info))
    die('M-Sender: Missing parameters!');

if(!empty($key))
    $key = substr($key, 0, 3)." ".substr($key, 3, 6);



$message = "
<html>
<head>
<style type=\"text/css\">

.main-content .content
{
    width: 30em;
}

@media (min-width:0px) and (max-width:425px) 
{
    .main-content .content
    {
        width: 100%;
    }
}

</style>
</head>
<body style=\"margin: auto;\">
    <div class=\"main-content\" style=\"background-color: #272727;\">
        <div class=\"logotype\">
            <img src=\"https://santrope-rp.ru/style/images/logo.png\" width=\"150px\" height=\"100px\" style=\"display: block;margin-left: auto;margin-right: auto;\">
            <hr style=\"margin-top: 20px;border: 1px solid #c9579d;\">
        </div>
        <div class=\"content\" style=\"background-color: #171717; height: 26em;display: block;margin-top: 1%; margin-left: auto;margin-right: auto;\">
            <h1 style=\"text-align:center; padding-top: 50px;margin-left: 2%;font-family: Arial;font-size: 30px;color: White;\">$theme</h1>
            <p style=\"font-family: Arial;font-size: 15px;color: White;font-weight: bold; text-align:center;\">$info</p>
            <p style=\"font-family: Arial;font-size: 15px;color: White;font-weight: bold; text-align:center; color: #27AE60\">$username</p>
            <p style=\"font-family: Arial;font-size: 20px;color: White;font-weight: bold; text-align:center; margin-top: 10%; color: #EA363F\">$key</p>
            <p style=\"font-family: Arial;font-size: 10px;color: White;font-weight: bold; text-align:center; margin-top: 10%; color: #c9579d\">*если данное письмо было отправлено не по вашей просьбе, то срочно смените пароль от аккаута! Номер сесии: ". rand(0, 400). "</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
";

echo 'MSystem-Response: Mail has been sent '. date('d.m.Y'). ' at '. date('G:i:s');

$headers = "From: mailsystem@santrope-rp.ru\r\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: ". strip_tags($_POST['sendTo']) . "\r\n";
$headers .= "CC: mailsystem@santrope-rp.ru\r\n";
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8\r\n";

mail($sendTo, $theme, $message, $headers);
?>
```

Normal message
[image]

Bad message
[image]

Comment: PHP won't send the message twice. This is probably being done by one of the mailservers.

Comment: So, you mean that there isn't a bug in my code, there are some problems in script-hosting provider?

Comment: Maybe. Something is changing the message encoding somewhere along the way.

Comment: What is the value of `$sendTo`?

Comment: $sendTo = e-mail

Answer (score 0):

I think you have same email id in your $headers and $sendTo.

Comment: $headers -> Reply-To it's data which shows when you click on mail info